# Get first and last date time from each date in query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I have is:

```
| Equipment Name | Event          | Time of Event           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| EX001          | Brake Active   | 2014-09-29 20:05:10 000 |
| EX001          | Brake Active   | 2014-09-29 20:07:10 000 |
| EX001          | Brake Active   | 2014-09-30 06:07:10 000 |
| EX001          | Brake Active   | 2014-09-30 18:05:10 000 |
| EX001          | Brake Inactive | 2014-09-29 20:05:45 000 |
| EX001          | Brake Inactive | 2014-09-29 20:06:10 000 |
| EX001          | Brake Inactive | 2014-09-29 23:01:10 000 |
```

and so on

I want to find out the number of Events in each date from first it happened count to last time it happened and show the date and the count of it. i have a query to count it in days but unable to show the fist and the last time it happened.

What I want is:

```
| Equipment Name | Event          | First Occurrence  | Last Occurrence   | Event Count |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EX001          | Brake Active   | 2014-09-29 20:05  | 2014-09-30 18:05  |     4       |
| EX001          | Brake Inactive | 2014-09-29 20:45  | 2014-09-29 23:01  |     3       |
```

and so on

All from one table

Please help guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(timeevent), MAX(timeevent), COUNT(*)
FROM equipment
GROUP BY equipmentname, event
```

Comment: yes it show ok but it shows first day of all dates of event and the las day of that event.

What i want is the start date of each day lets say 2014/2/1 06:00 to 2014/2/1 23:00 and the next line 2014/2/2 06:00 to 2014/2/2 23:00 and so on

Comment: Please, update your question, because in your sample the result you want is the first and the last date about event